# Why are there two different types of DataGridRow highlight colors, and why can't I control both of them?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF with its SelectedIndex field bound to the appropriate property in my viewmodel. When the window opens, I can see the selected row faintly shaded gray as compared to the rows that are not selected. If the user clicks the row, it changes to a shade of blue.

The reason this is a problem is because it seems I can only set the background color of rows which have been highlit by a user click, but not by the selected index changed programmatically. I have tried styles of the following type, but they only effect background color of rows clicked, not those set by SelectedIndex:

Example 1:

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Example 2:

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

So, how can I set the selected index hightlight color? Because my next step is to ignore user clicks. And anyway, what is the difference between these two types of row selection, the kind in which a user clicks, and the kind by which the selectedindex is set programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

```
//C#, WPF
dataGridInstance.Focus();       //make sure DataGrid is focused
dataGridInstance.SelectAll();   //select a row programmatically
```

These were my original questions used to search for this solution:

- Why does selecting row programmatically in WPF DataGrid results in
  gray highlight instead of blue?
- Why does selecting row in WPF DataGrid through code
  highlights differently compare to a mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

There are two styles for selection because the selection can be either active or inactive (when `element.IsFocused == false`).

Try this:

```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

However, since the visual distinction is there for a reason, I would recommend instead looking into [how focus works in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example, you may want to focus the grid when you initially show it or when you change its selection.